# Simplificar consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de agrupar la búsqueda. Osea tengo un campo que se llama $buski y me gustaría que busque en todos los campos tanto de una tabla como de la otra. Hasta ahora lo estoy definiendo a mano uno por uno tipo:

```
upper(nombre) like upper('%".$buski."%') OR
upper(cif) like upper('%".$buski."%') OR
upper(localidad) like upper('%".$buski."%')
```

¿Esto no hay una forma de ponerle el $buski solo una vez?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. A. Pon como se llaman las tablas en las que quieres buscar y qué tipo de relación hay entre ellas. B. Indica una idea de cómo quieres el resultado y el uso que le darías.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya lo ha resuelto amenadiel abajo y lo ha pillado a la primera :) no te digo que esté bien planteada la pregunta, pero tampoco es tan difícil de comprender si sabes mysql 

Comment: Con más detalles se te puede dar una respuesta más precisa. En BD lo que funciona bien cuando tienes pocos datos puede funcionarte mal en la medida en que la BD va creciendo. De todos modos me alegro de que se haya solucionado. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es muy elegante pero podrías concatenar los tres campos:

```
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(nombre, cif, localidad)) LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%')
```

Comment: Mas elegante que lo mío si es :)